# Trigger Lambda by number of SQS messages

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a SQS which will receive a huge number of messages. The messages keep coming to the queue.

And I have a use case where if the number of messages in a queue reaches X number (such as 1,000), the system needs to trigger an event to process 1,000 at a time.

And the system will make a chunk of triggers. Each trigger has a thousand messages.

For example, if we have 2300 messages in a queue, we expect 3 triggers to a lambda function, the first 2 triggers corresponding to 1,000 messages, and the last one will contain 300 messages.

I'm researching and see CloudWatch Alarm can hook up to SQS metric on "NumberOfMessageReceived" to send to SNS. But I don't know how can I configure a chunk of alarms for each 1,000 messages.

Please advice me if AWS can support this use case or any customize we can make to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: How do you plan executing 1K messages at a time? SQS only allows consumers to fetch 10 messages at once.

Comment: For the lambda we don't want to process 1000 messages at a time, we would like to have 1 SQS event which its body is the content of 1.000 messages.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve seems to be conflicting. If you are sending ONE message and this message has a body of 1000 attributes, for SQS it still is one message, so you'll never be able to configure an Alarm like that. Also keep in mind that your message has a limit of 256KB, depending on your objects size, this limit is going to be exceeded and you'll lose the message. Am I still missing something?

Comment: Hi @Thales, maybe my explanation is not good enough. I have copied here the same comment I put to Chris.  We have a process (process A) which keep generate files in S3. And the process (process B) we are trying to build is to group 1000 of files together to perform another business logic. After the process A generated a file to S3, they send a SQS message. And the process B must work as a batch of 1000 of files, we don't want to process B processes single single file

Comment: So, from what I understand, it's not one message with 1000 attributes. It would be 1000 messages and you want to process them at once, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: This is impossible to achieve with SQS, because you can only poll up to 10 messages at once.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you need to process these files when it reaches the number of a thousand?

Comment: We need to merge 1000 files together and then send the consolidated file to another system. That system requires a file which its content is a concatenation of1000 files

Comment: I have added an answer. Should you need more things let me know

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm taking a look on your answers now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189284/discussion-between-nghia-do-and-thales-minussi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after going through some clarifications on the comments section with the OP, here's my answer (combined with @ChrisPollard's comment):

Achieving what you want with SQS is impossible, because every batch can only contain up to 10 messages. Since you need to process 1000 messages at once, this is definitely a no-go.

@ChrisPollard suggested to create a new record in DynamoDB every time a new file is pushed to S3. This is a very good approach. Increment the partition key by 1 every time and trigger a lambda through [DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html). On your function, run a check against your partition key and, if it equals 1000, you run a query against your DynamoDB table filtering the last 1000 updated items (you'll need a Global Secondary Index on your CreatedAt field). Map these items (or use [Projections](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Projection.html)) to create a very minimal JSON that contains only the necessary information. Something like:

```
[
    {
     "key": "my-amazing-key",
     "bucket": "my-super-cool-bucket"
    },
    ...
]
```

A JSON like this is only 87 bytes long (if you take the square brackets out of the game  because they won't be repeated, you're left out with 83 bytes). If you round it up to 100 bytes, you can still successfully send it as one event to SQS, as it will only be around 100KB of data.

Then have one Lambda function subscribe to your SQS queue and then finally concatenate the 1 thousand files.

Things to keep in mind:

1. Make sure you really create the createdAt field in DynamoDB. By the time it hits one thousand, new items could have been inserted, so this way you make sure you are reading the 1000 items that you expected.
2. On your Lambda check, just run batchId % 1000 = 0, this way you don't need to delete anything, saving DynamoDB operations.
3. Watch out for the execution time of your Lambda. Concatenating 1000 files at once may take a while to run, so I'd run a couple of tests and put 1 min overhead on top of it. I.e, if it usually takes 5 mins, set your function's timeout to 6 mins.

If you have new info to share I am happy to edit my answer.

Comment: So every SQS message (which to generate a S3 file) will be 2 queries, 1 updating database to increase partition key and another fetch the value of the key. Am I correct? We are talking about here million of messages for every couple seconds. Thinking ...

Comment: No, that's not correct. DynamoDB streams will trigger your lambda function with the updated value already, so you don't need to query it. All you need to do is insert it.

Comment: It'd be something like s3 -> Lambda -> DynamoDB -> DynamoDBStreams -> Lambda - checks for % 1000 = 0 -> If yes, queries 1000 items on DynamoDB and sends message -> SQS -> Lambda to process the payload (this Lambda will then query s3 1000 times and concatenate the files)

Comment: So essentially we're talking about 1 SQS message every 1 thousand files uploaded to S3. Then Lambdas subscribed to DynamoDB streams and s3 events. This should work without much effort.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information. DynamoDB stream & Lambda, it appears a fit for the use case. I would like to confirm once more time the flow. The lambda (X) will generate a file to S3 and the insert (or update) partitionkey=1,2,3,4 --> 1000. And then DynamoDB stream will be triggered if the value is 1000, it will trigger a lambda. Am I correct?

Comment: Unfortunately DynamoDB stream events will be triggered upon every insert on Dynamo. So it will run for 1, 2, 3...1000. Then you handle it yourself. Got it?

Comment: Thank you. I totally got it. It means we need to see how to archive data after processing.

Comment: Kind of. After you run this query, then you send one message to SQS with the metadata of 1000 records. Then another Lambda subscribes to this SQS queue and concatenates the files. Then, once the file is concatenated, you'll very likely store it on S3. Does it make sense? If you have further questions we can move it to a chat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189265/discussion-between-nghia-do-and-thales-minussi).

Answer (score 0):

You can add alarms at 1k, 2k, 3k, etc...but that seems clunky.

Is there a reason you're letting the messages batch up? You can make this trigger event-based (when a queue message is added fire my lambda) and get rid of the complications of batching them.

Comment: Hi @Chris, we have a process (process A) which keep generate files in S3. And the process (process B) we are trying to build is to group 1000 of files together to perform another business logic. After the process A generated a file to S3, they send a SQS message. And the process B must work as a batch of 1000 of files, we don't want to process B processes single single file.

Comment: Perhaps writing to DynamoDB instead of SQS would be better for your workload. As an example, you can have your primary key be something like batch id, then increment a counter by 1 every time process A processes a file. When that reaches 1k, kick off process B and create a new batch in Dynamo.

Comment: Is that possible to trigger sns or sqs base on dynamodb data?

Comment: Not directly, but then you could write a Lambda to listen to the events. You'd need DynamoDB streams for it. @ChrisPollard, I think you should edit your answer with the DynamoDB approach. Seems very reasonable to me and will do what the OP wants. Achieving what he wants with SQS is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I handled a very similar situation recently, process-A puts objects in an S3 bucket and every time it does it puts a message in the SQS, with the key and bucket details, I have a lambda which is triggered every hour, but it can be any trigger like your cloud watch alarm. Here is what you can do on every trigger:

- Read the messages from the queue, SQS allows you to read only 10 messages at a time, and every time you read the messages, keep adding them to some list in your lambda, you also get a receipt handle for every message , you can use it to delete the messages and repeat this process until you read all 1000 messages in your queue. Now you can perform whatever operations are required on your list and feed it to process B in a number of different ways , like a file in S3 and/or a new queue that process B can read from.
- Alternate approach to reading messages: SQS allows you to read only 10 messages at a time, you can send an optional parameter 'VisibilityTimeout':60 that hides the messages from the queue for 60 seconds and you can recursively read all the messages until you dont see any messages in the queue, all while adding them to a list in lambda to process them, this can be tricky since you have to try out different values for visibility time out based on how long it takes to read 1000 messages. Once you know you read all the messages, you can simply have the receipt handles and delete all of them. You can also purge the queue but , you may delete some of the messages that came in during this process that are not read at least once.